# Cachesecond in Spring module

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-mvc

I am currently new to web programming and is trying out to learn spring framework.  I have basic understanding on Servlets and JSP.

Currently, I am confused on the property cacheSecond on the Spring Controller.  Can anybody point me to resource where I could understand below concepts?

I made some reading on browser caching but I am not sure if this is the same as the Response Caching being mentioned in the Spring documentation

Answer (score 2):

This is documented in the [API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/WebContentGenerator.html#setCacheSeconds%28int%29):

> Cache content for the given number of
>   seconds. Default is -1, indicating no
>   generation of cache-related headers.
>
> Only if this is set to 0 (no cache) or
>   a positive value (cache for this many
>   seconds) will this class generate
>   cache headers.
>
> The headers can be overwritten by
>   subclasses, before content is
>   generated.

This relates *only* to the HTTP cache headers, affecting browser behaviour. It has nothing to do with server-side response caching.

Incidentally, if you're just learning Spring, I recommend avoiding the Controller class hierarchy, which dates back to Spring 2.0, and focus instead on Spring 2.5-style [annotated controllers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-annotation). It's more intuitive and flexible, and is the recommended way to write Spring MVC apps now.

Comment: Thank you for your response... =) rex mercado